# Model field not updating in save()

Tags: django-models

In my Django `MyModel` I've created a new field `last_status_change` (a timestamp). Should be updated when that status changes.

However, even when a `print` shows that `last_status_change` is computed correctly, it doesn't get saved.
Is any field modification prohibited within save? What's the reason behind it? How to work around it?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Name')
  confirmation_status = models.CharField(
        choices=CONFIRMATION_STATUS_CHOICES,
        default='registered', max_length=20
    )
  last_status_change = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
      original = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
      if original.confirmation_status != self.confirmation_status:
        last_status_change = datetime.now()
    return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Please share your model.

Comment: Oh wait: could it be because to the RETURN ? I spared you the other things performed in the historical save(), which are basically a number of mail sends. I've not seen and "return super()" in the wild. "return super()" potentially nullifies everything that happened inside the method, inside telling the caller to just send the non-overriden method instead...

Comment: Doesn't fix it. Doesn't seem to harm either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it to the `self` object, so:

```
from django.utils import timezone


class MyModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Name')
    confirmation_status = models.CharField(
        choices=CONFIRMATION_STATUS_CHOICES, default='registered', max_length=20
    )
    last_status_change = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            original = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if original.confirmation_status != self.confirmation_status:
                self.last_status_change = timezone.now()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```